# Connect Oracle Server 12c from Windows Client SQLplus 11c

Tags: oracle

i have an oracle server 12c and would like to connect from an windows machine with sqlplus.

Server-Version is 12.2.0.1
SQLPlus is 11.2.0.1

when i connect to the server like "sqlplus user/pass@ORCL" i got the error

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

The credentials are correct. With SQLPlus 12.2 it works fine.

By checking support matrix it should be work also with 11.2.0

So here is my tnsnames.ora from the windowsclient

```
ORCL =
      (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS=
            (PROTOCOL=TCP)
            (HOST=10.162.6.52)
            (PORT=1521)
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SID=orcltok)
        )
    )
```

the PASSWORD_VERSION for the User is for 11g and 12c.
i have checked by from dba_users.

i hope someone have a tip for me.

Best wishes 
Oliver

Comment: best guess: your sqlplus 11g install is using a different TNSNames entry for ORCL and you're connecting to a different database, hence the ORA-01017.

Comment: hm, i think thats the correct TNSname when i connect with the configuration like **sqlplus user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=10.162.6.52)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcltok)))** i got the same error

Comment: try ez connect syntax sqlplus user/password@10.162.6.52:1521/orcltok

Answer (score 0):

I was very interested in your task, I put an experiment on oracle XE 11g and instant client 11.

```
 1. USER SCOTT password  Tiger 
 2. USER Scott password  TigeR

C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1>sqlplus.exe system/password@aws

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 19 22:05:00 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


SQL> alter user SCOTT identified by Tiger;

SQL> select * from all_users;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- ---------
XS$NULL                        2147483638 28-AUG-11
SCOTT                                  48 19-JAN-18
APEX_040000                            47 28-AUG-11
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       45 28-AUG-11
FLOWS_FILES                            44 28-AUG-11
HR                                     43 28-AUG-11
MDSYS                                  42 28-AUG-11
ANONYMOUS                              35 28-AUG-11
XDB                                    34 28-AUG-11
CTXSYS                                 32 28-AUG-11
OUTLN                                   9 28-AUG-11

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- ---------
SYSTEM                                  5 28-AUG-11
SYS                                     0 28-AUG-11

13 rows selected.
SQL> create user "Scott" identified by TigeR ;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to "Scott";

Grant succeeded.
SQL> select * from all_users;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- ---------
XS$NULL                        2147483638 28-AUG-11
Scott                                  51 19-JAN-18
SCOTT                                  48 19-JAN-18
APEX_040000                            47 28-AUG-11
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       45 28-AUG-11
FLOWS_FILES                            44 28-AUG-11
HR                                     43 28-AUG-11
MDSYS                                  42 28-AUG-11
ANONYMOUS                              35 28-AUG-11
XDB                                    34 28-AUG-11
CTXSYS                                 32 28-AUG-11

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- ---------
OUTLN                                   9 28-AUG-11
SYSTEM                                  5 28-AUG-11
SYS                                     0 28-AUG-11

14 rows selected.

C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1>sqlplus.exe "Scott"/Tiger@aws

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 19 22:10:31 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>

C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1>sqlplus.exe "Scott"/TigeR@aws

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 19 22:14:41 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1>sqlplus.exe /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 19 22:15:22 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect Scott/TigeR@aws
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SQL> connect "Scott"/TigeR@aws
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "Scott"
SQL>
```

**Example 2. sqlplus 12.2.0 instant client 12.2.0.1**

```
C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2>sqlplus.exe Scott/Tiger@aws

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Jan 22 09:42:08 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>


C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2>sqlplus.exe "Scott"/"Tiger"@aws

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Jan 22 09:44:46 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2>sqlplus.exe /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Jan 22 09:45:48 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn Scott/TigeR@aws
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SQL> conn "Scott"/TigeR@aws
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "Scott"
SQL>
```

If the user name contains letters in different registers, then sqlplus 11 and 12 translates the username to upper case always. If you run it like this
`sqlpus "Scott"/TigeR@aws` this is equivalent to `sqlpus "SCOTT"/TigeR@aws`.
If you first run the `sqlplus /nolog` command
and then `connect "Scott"/TigeR@aws`. That all connects.